# Does domain name needs to match with s3 bucket for static website hosting?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Does domain name needs to match with s3 bucket for static website hosting?
Can i map my domain **xyz.com** to the bucket **abc.com.s3-websits.us-east-1.amazonaws.com** by creating an alias record? Or bucket name must be **xyz.com.s3-websits.us-east-1.amazonaws.com**?

Comment: I think, If we use S3 without cloudfront it's the requirement and If we are using cloudfront its not required.

Comment: The comment about CloudFront is very important. May you would want to provide it in an answer and add a link to some official documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Bucket Name MUST match Domain Name, see pictures below.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

> These bucket names must exactly match your domain name.

For example, I have AppointmentsBook.net domain and also as a bucket name.

**Bucket**:

[image]

**Route53 with ALIAS pointing to the Bucket:**

[image]

I also recommend buying the domain via AWS in my case (AppointmentsBook.net) as its painful transferring one across from another domain name provider. AWS use GoDaddy behind the scenes. I also recommend people reserve their Name as a bucket as bucket names are globally unique.